# Laravel 8 soft delete get users posts and users deleted posts

Tags: php, laravel

I try a new thing in laravel.
I have an application that displays user posts, but when I want to delete a post from my account, it also appears in other accounts,
I use soft delete from laravel, I would just like to take over only the deleted posts by user_id on that account, not all deleted posts

What I have tried:

- lots of stuff, I think the main problem is blade, bcoz I try to use
  OpenTable list

**My controller**

```
use App\Models\Listing;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        
        $listings = Listing::latest();
        $trash = Listing::onlyTrashed()
                            ->get();
                            
        return view('dashboard',['listings' => $request->user()->listings],compact('trash','listings'));
    }

    public function trash($id){

        $delete = Listing::find($id)->delete();
        return Redirect()->back();
    }


    public function restore($id){
     

        $restore = Listing::withTrashed()
                            ->find($id)->restore();
        return Redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

**My view**

```
<x-app-layout>
    <section>
        <div 
        x-data="{
          openTab: 1,
          activeClasses: 'border-l border-t border-r rounded-t text-blue-700',
          inactiveClasses: 'text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-800'
        }" 
        class="p-6"
      >
        <ul class="flex border-b">
          <li @click="openTab = 1" :class="{ '-mb-px': openTab === 1 }" class="-mb-px mr-1">
            <a :class="openTab === 1 ? activeClasses : inactiveClasses" class="bg-white inline-block py-2 px-4 font-semibold" href="#">
                Your listings ({{ $listings->count() }})
            </a>
          </li>
          <li @click="openTab = 2" :class="{ '-mb-px': openTab === 2 }" class="mr-1">
            <a :class="openTab === 2 ? activeClasses : inactiveClasses" class="bg-white inline-block py-2 px-4 font-semibold" href="#">Trash ({{ $trash->count() }})</a>
          </li>
          <li @click="openTab = 3" :class="{ '-mb-px': openTab === 3 }" class="mr-1">
            <a :class="openTab === 3 ? activeClasses : inactiveClasses" class="bg-white inline-block py-2 px-4 font-semibold" href="#">Tab 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="w-full pt-4">
          <div x-show="openTab === 1"><section class="text-gray-600 body-font overflow-hidden">
            <div class="container px-5 py-12 mx-auto"> 
                <div class="mb-12 flex items-center">
                    <h2 class="text-2xl font-medium text-gray-900 title-font px-4">
                        Your listings ({{ $listings->count() }})
                    </h2>
                    <form action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        <button type="submit" class="ml-3 text-indigo-500">Sign Out</button>
                    </form><br>
                    <h2 class="ml-3 text-black-900">{{Auth::user()->email;}}</h2>
                    <h2 class="ml-3 text-black-900">{{Auth::user()->name;}}</h2>

                </div>
                <div class="-my-6">
                    @foreach($listings as $listing)
                        <a
                            href="{{ route('listings.show', $listing->slug) }}"
                            class="py-6 px-4 flex flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap border-b border-gray-100 {{ $listing->is_highlighted ? 'bg-yellow-100 hover:bg-yellow-200' : 'bg-white hover:bg-gray-100' }}"
                        >
                            <div class="md:w-16 md:mb-0 mb-6 mr-4 flex-shrink-0 flex flex-col">
                                <img src="/storage/{{ $listing->logo }}" class="w-16 h-16 rounded-full object-cover">
                            </div>
                            <div class="md:w-1/2 mr-8 flex flex-col items-start justify-center">
                                <h2 class="text-xl font-bold text-gray-900 title-font mb-1">{{ $listing->title }}</h2>
                                <p class="leading-relaxed text-gray-900">{{ $listing->company }} &mdash; <span class="text-gray-600">{{ $listing->location }}</span></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="md:flex-grow mr-8 mt-2 flex items-center justify-start">
                                @foreach($listing->tags as $tag)
                                    <span class="inline-block mr-2 tracking-wide text-indigo-500 text-xs font-medium title-font py-0.5 px-1.5 border border-indigo-500">{{ strtoupper($tag->name) }}</span>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                            <span class="md:flex-grow flex flex-col items-end justify-center">
                                <span>{{ $listing->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>
                                <span><strong class="text-bold">{{ $listing->clicks()->count() }}</strong> Apply Button Clicks</span>
                                <a href="{{ url('listing/edit/'.$listing->id) }}"> Edit</a>  
                                <a href="{{ url('trash/listing/'.$listing->id) }}"> Trash</a>     
   
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </section></div>
          <div x-show="openTab === 2">

            <div class="-my-6">
                
                @foreach( $trash as $items)
                    <a
                        href="{{ route('listings.show', $items->slug) }}"
                        class="py-6 px-4 flex flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap border-b border-gray-100 {{ $items->is_highlighted ? 'bg-yellow-100 hover:bg-yellow-200' : 'bg-white hover:bg-gray-100' }}"
                    >
                        <div class="md:w-16 md:mb-0 mb-6 mr-4 flex-shrink-0 flex flex-col">
                            <img src="/storage/{{ $items->logo }}" class="w-16 h-16 rounded-full object-cover">
                        </div>
                        <div class="md:w-1/2 mr-8 flex flex-col items-start justify-center">
                            <h2 class="text-xl font-bold text-gray-900 title-font mb-1">{{ $items->title }}</h2>
                            <p class="leading-relaxed text-gray-900">{{ $items->company }} &mdash; <span class="text-gray-600">{{ $items->location }}</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="md:flex-grow mr-8 mt-2 flex items-center justify-start">
                            @foreach($items->tags as $tag)
                                <span class="inline-block mr-2 tracking-wide text-indigo-500 text-xs font-medium title-font py-0.5 px-1.5 border border-indigo-500">{{ strtoupper($tag->name) }}</span>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                        <span class="md:flex-grow flex flex-col items-end justify-center">
                            <span>{{ $items->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>
                            <span><strong class="text-bold">{{ $items->clicks()->count() }}</strong> Apply Button Clicks</span>
                            <a href="{{ url('trash/restore/'.$items->id) }}"> Restore</a>  
                            {{-- <a href="{{ url('trash/listing/'.$trash->id) }}"> Trash</a>      --}}

                        </span>
                    </a>
                    @endforeach
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to add  ->whereCreatedBy($request->user()->id)

Comment: it works for me like this ...                             ->whereUser_id($request->user()->id)
 ....